# Modifying elements of an array through a pointer to its elements

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, pointer-to-array

Given the code:

```
int vector[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int *pv = vector, value = 3;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    *pv++ *= value;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%d, ", *(pv+i));
}
```

I expect each individual element of the array pointed to by `pv` to be multiplied by `3`.
Instead what I get as an output is:

```
32766, -1554513907, -527290408, -333409024, 32766,
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: second loop: `printf("%d, ", *--pv);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you incremented the pointer in the first `for` cycle in every loop, so when you get to the end of it, `pv` is already pointing to one past the end of `vector`.

For that reason all the values printed in the second `for` cycle represent residual values stored in addresses out of the bounds of the array, classic [undefined behavior](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3).

A quick fix would be to reset the pointer in between the two cycles:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    *pv++ *= value;
}

pv = vector; //here

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%d, ", *(pv + i));
}
```

Or use the *iterator* `i` in both cycles, since you already have it in the `for`, you might as well use it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    pv[i] *= value;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%d, ", pv[i]); 
}
```

With this method the pointer is not incremented, it's always pointing to the beginning of the array, accessing its indexes is safe.

Note that I used array notation `[]` as it's slightly less cluttered than the pointer dereference notation.

Comment: One could show the close linkage of the pointer initialization to the contents of the loops by making the loop initialization 'int i = 0, pv = vector;' in both loops.

Comment: @mpez0, that won't work, `pv` will be initialized as an `int`.

Comment: @mpez0 what you could do is `for (int i = 0, *pv = vector; i < 5; i++)` but of course `pv` will be a new local variable, not the original `pv`, and its lifetime is limited to the `for` loop.

Comment: yes, one has the choice of declaring `int * pv;` outside the loop (which is what i assumed), or `int *pv = vector` in the loop initializations to make it local to the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your program, the first for loop (ie)

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    *pv++ *= value;
}
```

Here, pointer(pv) gets incremented for 5 times and when the control exits the loop , pointer(pv) is now pointing to something which is out-of-bounds of your array size(vector)
Since you're using the same pointer variable in second for loop to print the array(vector) values, the garbage values gets printed.

You can solve this by reassigning your pointer variable(pv) back to the 1st position of your array either by

```
pv= vector;

// or

pv = &vector[0];
```

before your second for loop.